Gas Limit is over estimated for dex contract
i've been working with the dex smart contracts. Whenever i try to use the add liquidity function of the contract ,it has been calculating the gas limit of 1.3 billion in frontier1.1.0. In frontier v1.9.0, it is calculating 3 million for the same. When i've integrated the frontier v1.9.0 in the relay chain of version v1.9.0 and it is still calculating 1.3 billion
